# What makes Reedy model categories useful?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

I have been reading up a bit on the Reedy model structure on the category of simplicial objects in a model category $\mathcal{C}$ in Goerss-Jardine. One thing I find a bit unclear is what the Reedy model structure is exactly good for and what can I prove with it. I would really like some concrete theorems in homotopy theory whose proofs rely on the Reedy model structure. If anyone could give provide some applications and references, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, Goerss and Jardine use it to set up the homotopy spectral sequences of a cosimplicial space in the next chapter (following Bousfield and Kan).  All sorts of results use this spectral sequence in one way or another.